# Что такое "Прогрев JIT"?

Tags: c#

В статьях на хабре встретил в комментариях упоминание о так называемом "Прогреве JIT".

Что это такое?

Comment: это как прогрев шарепойнта, только для JIT. Загрузка всякого там кода в память и предоптимизация байткода, и подобные вещи.

Answer (score 8):

JIT означает Just In Time, то есть "точно вовремя". JIT-компиляция транслирует байт-код виртуальной машины в машинный код физической машины именно в тот момент, когда он требуется в первый раз. (Это в частности значит, что если метод ни разу не вызывался за время работы программы, он не транслируется.)

Метод, единожды скомпилированный, остаётся в памяти (кешируется) и при последующих вызовах выполняется сразу.

Соответственно при старте программы JIT-компиляция выполняется довольно часто, а по мере работы — всё реже и реже. В целом, программа начинает выполняться быстрее. Такое поведение и позволяет говорить о «прогреве».

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том что JIT комипиляторы имеют свойство оптимизировать выполняемый код если он выполняется часто. При нескольких прогонах одной и той же функции или метода, JIT старается оптимизировать эту функцию для наиболее быстрого выполнения.

Возможно вы замечали что в Java приложениях, что в .NET - только-только запущенная программа, работает медленнее чем та, которая уже какое-то время отработала. Естественно это при условии что корректно работают сборщики мусора и нет утечек памяти.

Comment: Я ни разу не слышал о JIT-компиляторе, который считает количество вызовов функции и перекомпилирует её с "включенной оптимизацией", если она вызывалась "довольно часто". JIT-компиляторы имеют свойство оптимизировать код под конкретную аппаратную конфигурацию, но делают это только один раз, при самом первом вызове функции.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Тем не менее JIT выполняет некоторые подсчеты в процессе выполнения и модифицирует код. Можно посмотреть тут www.codeproject.com/Articles/25801/JIT-Optimizations в разделе `The JIT's Approach`

Comment: @ApInvent, спасибо, интересная информация.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно имеется в виду следующее.

Когда вы загружаете программу (по которой не пробежался AOT-компилятор, наподобие ngen), каждый метод представлен в виде IL-кода. При этом в текущей версии .NET нет функциональности интерпретации IL-кода, IL-код должен бють скомпилирован в нативный код. Функция в памяти содержит заглушку, которая вызывает JIT-компилятор, который компилирует IL-код в нативный код, и заменяет тело функции на этот нативный код.

Таким образом, *первое* исполнение функции всегда длится дольше, чем последующие.

В контексте измерения производительности это может быть нежелательно, тогда перед измерением проводят *прогрев*: выполняют функцию один раз. После этого нативный код сгенерирован, и функция будет выполняться быстро.

---

Обратите внимание, что описанное поведение есть лишь особенность реализации в текущей версии майкрософтовской реализации .NET. Даже с этой версией приложение может быть скомпилировано AOT-компилятором, и в JIT-компиляция (а следовательно, и прогреве) более не будет необходимости. Даже сейчас можно скомпилировать приложение под .NET Native, и приложение не будет содержать IL-кода вовсе.

Также, в будущих версиях стратегия JIT-компилятора имеет право поменяться. Например, он может компилировать не один метод зараз, а целый класс, пространство имён или вообще сборку. Или он может собирать статистику и улучшать код инкрементально, как это делает HotSpot.

Поэтому не полагайтесь на это поведение.

Comment: Даже сейчас можно скомпилировать приложение под .NET Native, и приложение не будет содержать IL-кода вовсе. Ну если речь идет про UWP, правда

Comment: @V.Dmitriy: Ну так, нету JIT, нету и прогрева JIT.

Comment: Я к тому что .net native существует только для uwp. Простые приложения с помощью .net native не собрать