# sort(); java , 100 элементов сортирует быстрее чем 10

Tags: java

sort(); java , 100 элементов сортирует быстрее чем 10 почему так ?

```
 Random random = new Random();
    int[] array10 = new int[10];
    int[] array100 = new int[100];
    int[] array1000 = new int[1000];

    for (int i = 0; i < array10.length; i++) {
        array10[i]=random.nextInt(10000);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array100.length; i++) {
        array100[i]=random.nextInt(10000);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array1000.length; i++) {
        array1000[i]=random.nextInt(10000);
    }

// быстрая сортировка
        long start0 = System.nanoTime();
        Arrays.sort(array10);
        long end0 = System.nanoTime();
        long traceTime0 = end0-start0;

    long start1 = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(array100);
    long end1 = System.nanoTime();
    long traceTime1 = end1-start1;

    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    Arrays.sort(array1000);
    long end2 = System.nanoTime();
    long traceTime2 = end2-start2;

    // в наносекундах
    System.out.println("Qsort");
    System.out.println("10 elements: " + traceTime0+"ns");
    System.out.println("100 elements: " +traceTime1+"ns");
    System.out.println("1000 elements: " +traceTime2+"ns");
```

Консоль:

```
Qsort
10 elements: 974322ns
100 elements: 80737ns
1000 elements: 1101587ns
```

Comment: Попробуйте сделать несколько запусков программы и посмотреть результат. Возможно у вас массив в 100 элементов более упорядочен чем на 10 изначально.

Comment: тоже так думал, делал раз 10запусков , одно и тоже

Comment: Это почему-то связано с первой сортировкой, добавьте перед 10 элементами такую строку `Arrays.sort(new int[]{1});`, почему так происходит самому интересно

Comment: Тогда надо смотреть как реализован метод sort, там вроде в зависимости от длины массива выбирается разная сортировка, давно смотрел, уже не помню.

Comment: @Vennic, да там есть выбор другой сортировки, но он применяется только если больше 286 элементов

Comment: а, ну хотя если меньше 47 элементов, там дёргается InsertionSort

Comment: но всё равно, почему-то именно первый запуск занимает много времени, т.е. если добавить `Arrays.sort(new int[]{1});`, то он долго отрабатывает, а остальные будут нормально

Comment: Вы прогрели JVM? попробуйте сделать несколько тестовых запусков на больших массивах.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У вас неверная методика замера времени работы алгоритма. Попробуйте запустить сортировку меньшего массива последней, она станет заметно быстрее остальных: https://repl.it/repls/WordyLightgrayIntegers.

Вы замеряете всего один прогон алгоритма. В такой ситуации на результат замеров тут может влиять множество факторов - от "прогрева" JIT-компилятора и накладных расходов на загрузку класса `Arrays`  до случайных всплесков использования CPU другими программами. Сделайте хотя бы 10000 прогонов для каждого массива и возьмите среднее время - результат будет более точным. Также можете сделать ручной "прогрев" – несколько раз отсортировать массивы вхолостую, и только после этого приступать к замерам.

Ну и на десерт – если посмотреть на реализацию сортировки в методе `Arrays.sort()`, то можно увидеть, что для небольших массивов (до 286 элементов) используется алгоритм QuickSort, а для совсем маленьких (до 47 элементов) - сортировка вставками. У последней сложность варьируется от линейной до квадратичной, в зависимости от того, насколько отсортированы данные в исходном массиве. Это ещё один аргумент в пользу неточности единичного замера.

Answer (score 3):

Обернул код в while(true)
получаю такие результаты. Полагаю дело может быть связано в отсутсвием прогрева при замерах.

```
Qsort
10 elements: 367ns
100 elements: 2932ns
1000 elements: 39953ns
```

[Вот ссылка на вопрос про прогрев JIT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/449011/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2-jit)